# Did anyone get pgloader to work for migration from Mysql to Postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration

I have installed pgloader using yum install on centos 6.5. I cannot get pgloader to load the following file. My command on the shell is pgloader mysql.load

```
 LOAD DATABASE
 from      mysql://root:pass123@127.0.0.1:7777/demomysql
 into postgresql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/dbname?demopsql

WITH include drop, create tables, no truncate,
    create indexes, reset sequences, foreign keys

SET maintenance_work_mem to '128MB', work_mem to '12MB', search_path to 'demopsql'

CAST type datetime to timestamptz
  drop default drop not null using zero-dates-to-null,
  type date drop not null drop default using zero-dates-to-null

-- MATERIALIZE VIEWS film_list, staff_list

-- INCLUDING ONLY TABLE NAMES MATCHING ~/film/, 'actor'
-- EXCLUDING TABLE NAMES MATCHING ~<ory>

BEFORE LOAD DO
$$ create schema if not exists demopsql; $$;
```

I get the following log file

```
 pgloader     INFO     Logger initialized
 pgloader     WARNING  path entry '/usr/share/python-support/pgloader/reformat' does not        exists, ignored
 pgloader     INFO     Reformat path is [] 
 pgloader     INFO     Will consider following sections:
 pgloader     INFO       
 pgloader     INFO     All threads are started, wait for them to terminate
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is due to a bug.

Search for he variable *DEFAULT_REFORMAT_PATH* in /usr/share/pyshared/pgloader/options.py

Replace the path given with

/usr/share/pyshared/reformat.

You also have an error on the the file:  dbname?demopsql should be demopsql